# unable to add a comment new user need a 50 reputation.

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Apple devices causing "Land Attack" on Cisco ASA](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32503/apple-devices-causing-land-attack-on-cisco-asa/38580#38580)

I am experiencing an issue regarding  Apple devices causing "Land Attack" on Cisco ASA and want to add a comment asking for help with the same issue but when I try and leave a comment I am not allowed because I need a 50 reputation. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You do not use comments to ask a new question. You need to start a new question to ask your question. You can refer to the original question in your question.